# Is creating a package in Eclipse, equivalent of creating a new folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I'm not using Eclipse, so for my project when stated "create a new Java project called "Project 1", and import the above 2 files into a default package. "
Is that the equivalent of just throwing the two files into a folder and naming it  "Project 1"?

Because I'm using VS Code, If not how would I be able to create a package on VS Code?

Comment: [Here's a pretty good overview regard packages.](https://www.studytonight.com/java/package-in-java.php) In general, a package will only effect your code if you use the [protected](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/protected-keyword-in-java-with-examples/) access modifier so long as your pathing on any `import` statements is correct.

Comment: How is it possible in VS Code to code in Java without using Eclipse? Or do you miss the fact that in VS Code the Java language support _is_ Eclipse? To your question: yes, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_creating-a-source-code-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, about package in VS Code, the first thing we need to do is creating a folder.

When we create a folder under src, which we assume its name is **AAA**. if a .java file is created under AAA, there will be a statement **`package AAA;`** on the top line, like the screenshot shows:

[image]

If **`package AAA;`** isn't generated automatically, we should add it manually in every file which is under this folder.

Answer (score 0):

A package is a subdirectory below the src directory which is below the project directory.  You won't run into any issues using the default package, but it is generally good practice to put all your class and other files into a package so it is more organized.

Comment: Ok so can I just add my files into one folder? when using VS Code? , and will it make my code run differently?